# I need help with installing linux

Tags: boot

I have transferred Ubuntu into a USB using Mac Linux USB Loader. Now when I boot up my mac and choose the USB option to go into linux, it boots into OS X, Any idea why? any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install  refind or refit. Id recommend refind.  As it is newer and better IMO. I'll provide you links to both
Also Do a reboot after installing you should see a screen like this for refit

http://refit.sourceforge.net/img/screen2.png

or like this for Refind:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/refind.png

Download Links:

Refind:  http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Refit: http://refit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I actually figured it out but forgot to take this down. Thank you again!